# Do I need to push metadata after changing only a signing certificate?

Tags: linux, openssl

Using shibboleth on Linux, I'm exposing a service that uses SAML to the public. Previously I have used a self-signed cert as all the SAML traffic has been internal.

Using the same key, I made a CSR and got a shiny new cert that's signed by a proper CA.

My question is, in shibboleth, what's needed for this change? From what little I know, SAML doesn't really use the signing chain. The new and old certs have the same MD5 signature after comparing them with:

```
openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in server.crt| openssl md5
```

Shibboleth's config outlines a procedure for rollover of **decryption** keys, but I assume a signing cert isn't covered by that.

I'm hoping to hear I can just sub in the new cert, but if not, what I must update and where--like, do I need every app that connects to get updated metadata, for example.

Thanks in advance for your wisdom!